# NRE to Indian savings account taxable ? if returned back to India for good?

Tags: taxes, india

Hi I have returned back to India from abroad, i have NRE account.  Can i continue that account till i spend that money ! If i transfer it to my savings account in india, is it taxable ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i continue that account till i spend that money

No you have to convert this to Ordinary Savings Account. If you want to repatriate the funds in future or need that flexibility; you can move the money into RFC account [Resident Foreign Currency] and even hold it in USD/EUR/etc. Both the principal and the interest can be repatriated without any paperwork.

> If i transfer it to my savings account in india, is it taxable ?

Income earned when your status was NRI is not taxable and you can transfer this into Savings account without any tax consequences in India (or abroad for that matter). Any interest generated in the Savings account *after the transfer* will be taxable as per tax brackets, but there is no tax on the money transferred *into* the Savings account from your NRE (or NRO) account.